# Iptables policy to accept incoming SSH and ICMP only

Tags: iptables

I ran the following `iptables` commands to allow incoming SSH and ICMP connections and block all others.

```
sudo iptables -F INPUT
sudo iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT && sudo iptables --policy OUTPUT 
ACCEPT && sudo iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 5051  -j REJECT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

The resulting iptables listing looks like this

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             match-set minuteman dst,dst tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ita-agent reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             match-set minuteman dst,dst tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I see that line accepting SSH comes before the one that rejects all other traffic. But I am still not able to SSH into the machine.

Any clues why this is not working?

Comment: What about accepting ssh OUTPUT?

Comment: I don't need to accept SSH output

Comment: Yes, you need to accept output SSH traffic --  ( iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT )

Comment: Actually, it works fine as long as I don't run the last rule: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT`

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to allow SSH and ICMP

```
# Flush the FW Rules 
iptables -F
iptables  -X

# Block all traffic
iptables  -P INPUT DROP
iptables  -P FORWARD DROP
iptables  -P OUTPUT DROP


# Allow SSH
iptables  -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables  -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT


# Allow ICMP (ping)
iptables  -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables  -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Shouldn't the allow statements be above the block statements